# Copy data from nested json to multiple SQL tables

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following json data in ADL.

```
{
        "stores": [
            {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "Item 1",
                        "price": 20.04
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Item 2",
                        "price": 22.06
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Item 3",
                        "price": 24.08
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Store 1"
            },
            {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "Item 4",
                        "price": 10.04
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Item 5",
                        "price": 12.06
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Item 6",
                        "price": 14.08
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Store 2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Need to copy this data to SQL DB with two different tables.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Stores (
  Store_ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
  Store_Name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Stores PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID),
  CONSTRAINT UK_Stores UNIQUE(Store_Name)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Items (
  Item_ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
  Item_Name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  Item_Price money NULL,
  Item_Store_ID int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Items PRIMARY KEY (Item_ID),
  CONSTRAINT UK_Items UNIQUE(Item_Name),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Items_Stores FOREIGN KEY (Item_Store_ID) REFERENCES dbo.Stores (Store_ID)
);
```

I would like to create an entry in the Stores table first based on Store_Name and create Items in Items table with Item_Store_ID as Store_ID in Stores table for that Store_Name.

How to achieve this in ADF pipeline?

Comment: Given your table has a foreign key and you presumably need to pick that up, you might be better off with a Copy activity with a stored proc sink.  Pass the JSON is as a parameter and allow the proc to handle the JSON processing, eg using `OPENJSON`, `JSON_VALUE` and `MERGE` for example.  Also, what is the target database?

Comment: It is Azure SQL DB

Comment: I have prepared an answer but I need to know is this homework, interview question or project work?

Comment: :) Proof of Concept. I am trying your suggestion. Will try and come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using **Stored procedure activity with Lookup activity as input** in ADF.

I am using the **same JSON data** for my repro.

Please follow the below steps:

- First create your tables `Items` and `Stores` in Azure SQL DB with your script.
- Then create a **Stored procedure** to copy data from JSON data to multiple tables like below.

  ```
   create or alter procedure dbo.newproc @json nvarchar(max)
   as
   begin
   INSERT INTO dbo.Stores(Store_Name) 
       SELECT JSON_Value (ok.value,'$.name')
       FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.stores') as ok;
   INSERT INTO dbo.Items(Item_Name,Item_Price,Item_Store_Id) 
       SELECT JSON_Value (p.value,'$.name') as Item_Name,
              JSON_Value (p.value,'$.price') as Item_Price,
              (select Store_ID from dbo.stores where Store_Name in (JSON_Value 
       (c.value,'$.name')))
       FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.stores') as c
       cross apply openjson(c.value,'$.items') as p;
       end
  ```

In the above script I am inserting the **foreign key `Item_Store_Id` in `items` table based on the `Store_name`** in the `Stores` table.

- Run the stored procedure script and get back to ADF.
- In ADF create the linked services for the Azure Data Lake Gen2 and Azure SQL Database.
- Also, create the dataset for the JSON from Data Lake. Here you don’t need to create the target dataset as you had given before in stored procedure itself.
- Now, create a Lookup activity by dragging from ADF activities.
- Give the source JSON dataset to the lookup activity and check the preview of the dataset and **uncheck the First row only** in it.

[image]

- Now search for Stored procedure in the activities and drag it and **join the lookup with JSON**.
- We are using the **Lookup to pass the JSON file as string parameter** to the stored procedure.
- Now, click on Stored procedure and select the linked service of Azure SQL DB and test the connection then select the **Stored Procedure name from the drop down**.

[image]

- After selecting it, click on import and give the **JSON file as string to the Stored Procedure from the Lookup activity output** like below.

  `@string(activity('Lookupjson').output.value[0])`

[image]

- Execute this pipeline and you can see **the data from JSON is copied to multiple tables in SQL Database**.
  [image]

**Stores table:**
[image]

**Items table:**
[image]